# What is an "infinitive"?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, bare-infinitive

I've heard that a verb usually follows the 'infinitive' but how does one define an 'infinitive'?

Comment: Simple "what is the definition of X word" questions are likely to be closed as off-topic. Is there something more unique / specific you're asking?

Comment: Something people split.

Comment: @Orbling: Something many great writers have chosen to quite justifiably split!

Comment: Do verbs usually follow infinitives?  Isn't it the other way around, if anything?

Comment: @PLL: Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 4):

You might see the infinitive is the form of the verb that has most of the following features:

- it is the form that does not carry any of the inflections that essentially any "productive" verb can carry that restrict the interpretation of that verb;
- it is the form that can be the complement of a modal auxiliary;
- it is the form that may be specified by a special selection of prepositions (sometimes called "pre-infinitival prepositions": "to" in English, "zu" in German, "de" in French etc).

Beware of just saying that the infinitive is the form "without inflection", because some languages have specific endings/inflections that are actually *added* to the root to specify "infinitive", and infinitives may allow certain modifications e.g. to mark perfective aspect in Slavic languages, to mark reflection/voice in various European languages. They're the form "without inflection" so long as you understand "inflection" in a particular way.

Answer (score 3):

The infinitive is the basic or root verb form, uninflected.

For example, in "to work" the infinitive is "work":

> We didn't come here to have fun, we came here to work.

Other forms are derived from the infinitive:

> I worked.
>
> He works.
>
> You'll usually find me working.

And so on.

Comment: Isn't 'work' a noun?

Comment: It can be that too. But I'm using it here as a verb.

Comment: Actually, in English, the infinitive is also the verb with *to*.  You are talking about the bare infinitive, but with *to* it is considered the full infinitive.  You might be calling "infinitive" what I would call the verb stem.  In English it usually looks like the bare infinitive.  In other languages, e.g. French, there is a clear difference between stem and infinitive, because of the infinitival suffix.

Answer (score 3):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* defines an infinitive thus:

> Those with a plain form are infinitival, and are subdivided into *to*-infinitivals and bare infinitivals depending on the presence or absence of the VP [verb phrase] subordinator *to*.
>
> 1. *It was Kim's idea **to invite them all***. [*to*-infinitival]
> 2. *She helped them **prepare their defence***. [bare infinitival]

Comment: Huge *CGEL* fan here, but this definition "infinitival: those with a plain form" is seriously unclear taken by itself. If I remember the context correctly, "those" refers to something like "non-finite clauses" that needs more explanation. "Plain form" just means the verb isn't inflected (*invite*, not *invites/invited/inviting*; and particularly *be*, not *is/are/were/etc.*).

Comment: Fair point. It's really describing clauses not word forms. I really wanted to point out that it's not the classical "to work" for example.

Answer (score 1):

Verbs are used various different ways:

> We **invite** friends over every night. It **is** fun. (present tense)
>
> We **invited** Kaitlin. She **was** busy though. (past tense)
>
> We are **inviting** someone new. He likes **being** the center of attention. (*-ing* form)

The infinitive is another way to use a verb. In English, the easiest ways to identify the infinitive are

- the word *to* usually comes before the verb phrase;
- the verb does not take a suffix *-s*, *-ed*, or *-ing*, and in particular, the word *be* can be used as the verb, rather than *is*, *was*, or *being*.

> We don’t want to **invite** him. He likes to **be** the center of attention. (infinitive)

The infinitive can't be the main verb of a sentence. It often comes after another verb, like *want* or *likes* above. But not always:

> To **invite** her would be a mistake. (infinitive as subject)
>
> This is another way to **use** the infinitive. (infinitive after *way*)

The infinitive appears without *to* in a few places, particularly after the modal auxiliary verbs *can/could/may/might/will/would/shall/should/must* and after a few other verbs like *help*.

> He can **be** the center of attention if that’s what he wants. (infinitive after *can*)
>
> Help me **invite** all these people to our party. (infinitive after *help*)