# Why we don't use "s" when ask with "can"?

Tags: british-english

We don't use "play**s**" in a question "Can he play the piano?". Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are modal verbs finite or non-finite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114103/are-modal-verbs-finite-or-non-finite)

Comment: Also related, the question may not be identical but the answers are the same [What is the infinitive of “can”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/what-is-the-infinitive-of-can) and [Modal vs Non-Modal vs Auxiliary modal vs Conjugated Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137970/modal-vs-non-modal-vs-auxiliary-modal-vs-conjugated-verb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use the verb 'can' to mean 'be able to', when talking about ability or permission, we use the base (infinitive) form of the verb. This is true both in a straightforward statement, such as he can play the piano, he can jump one metre in the air, and also in a question, such as can he play the piano? How high can he jump?

[Can (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/can)