# Rephrase "to love is to can"

Tags: paraphrasing

So there is a non profit organization in Greece called "Μπορούμε" which translates to "we can".
Me and some friends we volunteered there as a valentine's day event to give back to the community because we want to support it. We would like to write a small article about our event.
The title, as of yet, is "To love is to can".

I despise the way it sounds!! "To can" sounds odd to my ears. Is there any way we can rephrase it?
The meaning we're going for is something along the lines of we love & we can but in a catchy way to grab attention.

Comment: Perhaps “If you love you can”. Sorry but requests of slogans are off-topic here.

Comment: See [What is the infinitive of “can”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102554/what-is-the-infinitive-of-can) Or perhaps the "slogan" you're looking for is [***True love conquers all***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22True+love+conquers+all%22)

Comment: What's actually wrong with "We love and we can"? Or maybe, since you did do something, "We love, we can and we do"? I'm going to mark this as a duplicate, but I'm afraid that requests for slogans are likely to be either writing advice or opinion-based. We do have a [phrase-request] tag but requirements for those questions [are quite strict](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) and simply "in a catchy way" won't cut it, sorry. If you can satisfy the requirements, by all means ask another question.